# Why should I use nested functions instead of writing the whole code in the main function?

Tags: javascript

Doesnt making nested functions make it more complicated than what it has to be? Why not write the code in the main function and skip the nested functions?

Comment: Why do you think modularising your code by abstracting into functions makes it more complicated? (Doesn't really matter whether they're nested or not).

Comment: First of all, do you know why functions are used in the first place in a code?

Comment: Nested functions can be very useful in a certain context. Without code example, it is hard to define the context and a lot of (wrong) assumptions are made. Provide some code so we can give you more helpful answers

Answer (score 1):

Breaking codes into small functions makes it more readable and easy to understand, mostly if you give to each small function a name that reflect what the function does. These functions may also be reusables so you can reduce code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

The main reasons are reusability and abstraction. From https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_functions.htm:

> A function is a group of reusable code which can be called anywhere in
>   your program. This eliminates the need of writing the same code again
>   and again. It helps programmers in writing modular codes.
>
> You must have seen functions like alert() and write(). We were using
>   these functions again and again, but they had been written in core
>   JavaScript only once.

If you are using someone else's code, you don't have to know their entire function code. All you need to know is how to use it: it's parameters, return types, etc.

Comment: "*in the earlier chapters.*" of what?

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for pointing that out. Fixed that :)

Answer (score 1):

'nested functions' is very vague.

If you are relating to a function inside a function then that's most likely a closure you are referring to

> A closure is the combination of a function and the lexical environment
>   within which that function was declared.
>   [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

However if you mean separate functions in form of for example:

```
function firstFunction(){

}

function secondFunction(){

}
```

Then what you've stated is wrong, it's easier to work with multiple smaller functions than one big function. Having multiple smaller functions provides great Code modularity which helps reusing code thus reducing the lines of repeating code. It's also easier to maintain (upgrade, rewrite, make changes), copy and paste (to another project for example). While working on your code it is much easier to debug a smaller function rather than a function with 1000 lines of code, also if you're working in a development environment, where multiple developers work on the code, they are not going to spend 15 minutes reading a single function containing hundreds of lines, it's much easier to break it.

Answer (score 0):

Nested functions allow staggering of functionality in a sequential manner. You can abstract functionality into separate functions, and then call them from anywhere in the program. The idea is that wrapping functionality within functions stops them from interfering with each other causing incorrect data output.

Answer (score 0):

> Doesn't making nested functions make it more complicated than what it has to be?

If you use an IDE and try to name your functions in a good way, they won't.

By reference to the "Refactoring" by Martin Fowler, you should extract code sections which do a portion of the whole a process to smaller functions to make the main function more readable.

Also splitting code to smaller functions make them more testable, therefore you can easily test each part of the code.
And If you develop in an OOP manner it helps others to override a part of the code which helps you to make more reusable components and decrease tight-coupling.

Comment: One does not need an IDE to use functions

Comment: I meant using an IDE with static analysis which helps to navigate around code without searching around for the whole project would be very grateful to extract methods and make code more readable.